# How to use if statement to match multiple criteria and delete selected rows in table

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out an IF function that will delete specific rows in a table when criteria not met, to be used in VBA code(not required I'll write it myself, just need help with the formula) when I manage to get the function working.

I've got a table with the following headings:

```
Article UOM Site    SOH

5855    CS  M01     0.25
5855    SW  M01     0
5855    CS  M04     49
5855    SW  M04     58
5855    SW  M04L    0
5855    CS  M04L    0
30623   SW  M01     142.08
30623   CS  M01     0
30623   SW  M01L    297.42
30623   CS  M01L    0
194272  CS  M27L    11.5
194272  SW  M27L    0
198552  SW  M27     0
198579  SW  M01     80
198579  SW  M04     109
228803  SW  M14     4.67
228803  CS  M14     3.29
344486  CS  M15L    0
344486  SW  M15L    -0.17
373926  SW  M18L    0
373926  CS  M18L    0
```

If tried different IF and MATCH functions, but it's not working as it should because I'm not sure how to word it anymore.

The formula should work something like this:

1. IF the "Article" and "Site" is the same as another row, THEN
2. check "SOH" and choose the one not =0 (could be + or - value), BUT
3. IF both are =0 or both have values, THEN
4. Choose the one with "UOM" =CS
5. DELETE the other row not chosen above (I'll do this, just need a way of marking the one that needs deleting)

**EXAMPLE 1**

1. First 2 lines have the same "Article" and "Site"
2. "SOH" for the 1st line has a value not =0, where the 2nd line =0, so choose the 1st line
3. not applicable
4. not applicable
5. DELETE 2nd line

**EXAMPLE 2**

1. Line 3 and 4 have the same "Article" and "Site"
2. not applicable, next option
3. both have values THEN
4. choose 3rd line because "UOM"=CS
5. DELELTE 4th line

If anyone has any easier ways, it would be appreciated. I want to use the formula with the rest of my VBA code.

Comment: Welcome to SO Simone, this is not a free code service, so you should show us first what you have. Besides that... Do you have any priority on your criterias? I mean on your first example the column to compare is the last one while on the second  is the second column. Is there any pattern or anything that would make it simple? If not, you must write a ton of criterias, you could use `Select Case` along with the `If`

Comment: I believe the question is just asking for how to write an IF statement that will somehow flag which rows need to be deleted. I don't think the code is required on how to filter or loop through the rows to do the deleting part. If I'm right, then including "and delete selected rows" in the question is misleading in making people think that is part of the required solution, instead of it just giving the context which is not actually needed. If I'm wrong, then yeah starting code would be expected before assisting with that too.

Comment: @Michael Thank you, I'm checking the formula below. So far it seems perfect. I'm not asking for the code, like you mentioned, just help with the formula, I'm doing the code myself. I'll adjust my question to make that clear. After testing I'll mark your answer, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you never have more than 2 rows for the same Article and Site and there's never more than one row for the same Article and Site with UOM = CS, then this should identify the rows to delete:

`=IF(COUNTIFS([Article],[@Article],[Site],[@Site])>1,IF(COUNTIFS([Article],[@Article],[Site],[@Site],[SOH],"<>0")<>1,IF([@UOM]<>"CS","Delete",""),IF([@SOH]=0,"Delete","")),"")`

It first checks if there is a duplicate for the same Article and Site.

- If there is, it then checks whether they both have zero or non-zero SOH.

  - If both have zero or non-zero SOH, delete the one with UOM <> CS
  - Else, delete the one with SOH = 0